# Using a Phase-Locked Loop to synchronize time for clients in a multiplayer game

Tags: c++, time, network-programming, game-engine

I am reading the book Development and Deployment of Online Multiplayer Games Volume 1 and looking at chapter 3, the section about time synchronization. An excerpt from this chapter follows -

> As for implementing PLL itself in software, it is *much* easier than it might seem at first glance. Essentially, it consists of a phase detector (which says by-how-much our prediction-of-the-next-Server packet went wrong, which is basically the difference between *predicted_time* and *arrival_time*), integrator (can be as simple as "multiply current integrator value by k<1 and add new value" on each oscillation), and a variable-frequency oscillator (which can be implemented by simply using the current output of the integrator to calculate the period of the next oscillation, which in turn will be implicitly based on the Client's system clock frequency, but this is exactly the point).

The output of the oscillator will be the *predicted_time*.

I am particularly confused on how to get the integrator value, or what to even originally define it as. I can start the prediction of the next server packet as the now time + 100ms, but when it comes to figuring out how to use the integrator value to predict the next value I'm at a loss.

The book mentions k should be very close to 1, but strictly less than 1, and the integrator output shouldn't change the oscillation period by more than a factor of 1e-4 (.0001) or so. Also, with 0 input from the integrator, the oscillator should generate normal/expected frequency of my server's packets.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am also studying it. Although I am not entirely sure how to implement it yet, I think it's something like this (pseudocode):

```
predicted_period_time = 1/20 // server runs at 20fps
last_time_packet_arrived = Time.now()
K = 0.5 // This value the author says you need to test to find the best value.
while game.is_running()
sleep(predicted_period_time)
packet = buffer_on_receipt.unqueue()
real_measured_time = packet.time_arrived - last_time_packet_arrived
error_time = predicted_period_time  - real_measured_time
predicted_period_time += error_time * K
last_time_packet_arrived = packet.time_arrived
end while
```

Something along those lines. You're basically adjusting your frame loop according to error multiplied by a constant.